# JavaFX Scene Builder - line break in button's text

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

How can I add a line break to a button's text when using the Scene Builder? Doing it in the controller's code (of the Java file) gives me what I want:
`button.setText("one\ntwo");`
results in
`one`
`two`
being displayed. But inserting `one\ntwo` into the button's text when using Scene Builder (and without the Java code mentioned above) results in `one\ntwo` being displayed.

There is a "Wrap Text" checkbox with which I was unsuccessful. I guess this is for making the text wrap when the button is not wide enough, but this is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Scene Builder, you can switch to multi-line mode, and start adding text and new lines.

[image: Button text]

With your text:

[image: Button text 2]

Then, if you edit the FXML file you will see that the usual line return `\n` is replaced with the html encoding for line feed: `&#10;`. So in your case:

```
<Button fx:id="button" text="one&#10;two" />
```

Comment: That Scene Builder ... the extra button next to that text field only appears when the mouse hovers over it. But why should an unknowing user place the mouse there? :-)

Comment: Yes, there're quite a few 'hidden' options. Usually all the controls in the Inspector tab have a not visible button on the right with extra options, mainly to reset to default values, visible only on hovering.